# Android IAP Error RESULT_SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE

Tags: android, in-app-billing, subscription, google-play, recurring

Strange error that I'm seeing when trying to restore transactions:

```
06-29 10:04:30.765: I/BillingService(16135): checkResponseCode got responseCode: RESULT_SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE
```

I've come across [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10447801/android-in-app-billing-result-service-unavailable) [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10527162/android-restore-transactions-returns-result-service-unavailable) SO questions which have been promising, but ultimately it seems like they are caused by different issues. But they did at least give me a hint on what else I might look at, and I see this in logcat:

```
06-29 10:04:30.694: E/Finsky(16231): [1] NotifyingErrorListener.onErrorResponse: Server error on InAppPurchaseInformationRequest: com.android.volley.ServerError
```

which comes back in response to the request to restore transactions. GPlay is fine, it's running no problems ... and I'm also able to purchase another IAP that I had before (this only started happening in the last few days as I've been finishing up a recurring billing/subscription implementation).

Any thoughts would be appreciated, thanks!

*Edit: Upon closer inspection ... it looks like it is in fact the same as one of the other issues reported, though none of them reported the error I was seeing above as far as I could tell.*

```
06-29 11:26:08.142: E/Volley(16498): [14] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 429 for https://android.clients.google.com/vending/api/ApiRequest
```

This is a rather unfortunate error that obviously many people are seeing. Any idea how to recover from this? is the answer just "Wait"? I was having this problem yesterday, so if it really is due to me making the request too often, I would have expected it to go through at least once this morning when I retried it, which wasn't the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem, and "solved it" by waiting. However, I can only tell that lockout is longer than 2 days and shorter than three weeks... I put it aside for some time and didn't test. Only solution is probably to wait, although request to google support may help or clear the matter.